# What qualifies a ux designer?

Tags: usability, website-design, mobile, interaction-design, ux-designer

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/6-traits-prove-you-good-ux-designer-yuting-liu

The article said 6 traits can qualify a great ux designer,
what do you think of it?

Good UX Designer Never Feel Satisfied

Good UX Designer Always Have a Plan B, C, even D…

Good UX Designer Hold a Strong Holistic View

Multiple Means To Do Customer Research

Good UX Designers Don’t Rely On Their Own Judgments

...